# Insert comments after closing bracket using Android Studio automatically

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

Is it possible to get comments to be placed automatically at the end of a method with Android Studio?

```
  return new MaterialApp(

    ); // MaterialApp
```

Comment: I haven't found the setting that allows to enable that in IntelliJ in Android Studio. I'd suggest to create a feature request in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/

Comment: I found out that this happens in Visual Studio Code with the flutter plugin and there is called ghost comments.

Comment: Yes, it's a dartanalyzer feature, I just didn't find a way to enable it in AS. In IntelliJ there is a checkbox in Preferences > Editor > General > Appearance > Show closing labels in Dart source code

Answer (score 64):

Closing labels are now supported in Android Studio 3.1 with the latest Dart and Flutter plugin

[image]

(last checkbox at the bottom)

Disable checkbox and **restart** IDE

Comment: This is such a terrible stress-inducing feature that adds cognitive overhead. So glad I was able to turn it off to clean up my code and now things are easier to read! Brace highlighting should be enough to sort things out.

Comment: This is now turned on by default, which is awful.

Answer (score 5):

As in Android Studio 3.4 the location name changes to:

```
File > Settings... > Editor > General > Appearance
```

Tick the last checkbox - "Show closing labels in Dart source code".

Answer (score 0):

Just ctrl + f in settings and paste:

```
Show closing labels in Dart source code
```

Disable checkbox and **restart** the IDE

Now your code is readable!